# How to download Glacier storage class objects?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

I have migrated my large set of files from s3 storage class to Glacier storage class via a lifecycle policy due to the cost optimization. When i try to download the file from AWS Console it asks me to restore them first. The files will be available to download based on the mode we chose when we are performing restoration. If it is "Expedited" mode it will be restored within 1-5 mins. But  my concern is, Can't we directly download them with AWS SDK for python or nodejs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Amazon S3 objects in a Glacier storage class are not available for download. **They must first be restored, regardless of access method.**

Once restored they can be downloaded like normal S3 objects.

See: [Restoring an archived object - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/restoring-objects.html)

Comment: This is correct. If you have a large number of objects to retrieve, using S3 Batch to restore them (see https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-batch-operation-initiate-restore/)  will be more efficient than restoring them through the console or via API/CLI.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But when i try to download the file from Glacier using aws sdk for node and 'file-saver' node library it's downloading. i was wondering why it's happening